# glm function in split experiment in r

Tags: r, glm, nlme

I am carrying out an split experiment with microbiology. Totally 3 blocks I set: A,B,C; each block contains 2 replicates; each replicate contains 2 species. I want to test if the density ratio of these 2 species change with time.

I write this code:

```
y19 <- cbind(data19$density.E, data19$density.P)
model19 <- glmer(y19 ~ time + (1|block), binomial, data = data19)
summary(model19)
```

it works, but show warning:

> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
> Warning messages:
> 1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
> 2: In eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-integer counts in a binomial glm!

I learned that glm function can be also used, but I dont know the format of split experiments in glm, I can only write:

```
model19 <- glm(y19  ~ time * block, binomial, data = data19)
```

what the right format of glm of my question

Comment: Why didn't you try rescaling and why binomial instead of poisson? What is the target variable?

Comment: `y19` needs to be 0's or 1's for a binomial glm() to work.

Comment: @Quality the density are already transformed, and if I use poisson, it shows  error with dimension mismatch. but glmer model also has warning: 1.boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular').  and 2. In eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-integer counts in a binomial glm. I dont know if these warning matter?

Comment: @MrSwaggins ok, thank you. do you know what the format to write for split experiments in glm?